# Why does function drop a wrong index off the matrix?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I wrote a simple function that generates a matrix from a source one based on a set of indexes it gets as an argument. When I tried it on some test vectors, it did work, but now it behaves in a way I can't grasp.

I use pandas' dataframe to create and alter the matrix.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

def matrix_creator(set):
    matrix = L
    print("set", set)
    print("matrix", matrix)
    for i in range(len(L)):
        if i not in set:
            print(i)
            matrix.drop([i], axis=0, inplace=True)
            matrix.drop([i], axis=1, inplace=True)
    return matrix

preL = [[49.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, -6.0, -7.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, -5.0, 0.0, -5.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -6.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -5.0, -1.0, -7.0, -5.0, -2.0, -6.0, -5.0, -4.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.5, -1.0, -2.0, -1.0, -2.0, -4.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, -5.0, -4.0, -5.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, -5.0, -1.0, -5.0, 0.0, -1.0], [-1.0, 46.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, -3.5, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0], [-3.0, -3.0, 37.0, 0.0, -2.0, -3.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0], [-1.0, -3.0, 0.0, 28.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-6.0, -4.0, -2.0, -1.0, 42.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -4.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -1.0, -3.0, -2.5, -1.0, -2.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0], [-7.0, -3.5, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, 40.0, -5.0, -3.0, -4.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -5.0, -3.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -3.0, -4.0, -5.0, -5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -5.0, -3.0, -3.0, -2.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -5.0, -4.0, -3.0, -4.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -3.0, -2.0, -1.0, -2.0, -5.0, 35.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, -6.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -2.0, -4.0, 0.0, -4.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -10.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0], [-3.0, -1.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, 49.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, -4.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -2.0, -3.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -1.0, -3.0], [-1.0, -3.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, -4.0, -3.0, -3.0, 33.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -4.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, -9.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-5.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, 34.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, -4.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0], [0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 26.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0], [-5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 23.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0], [-2.0, -2.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 35.0, -3.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, -1.0, -4.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.5, 0.0, -1.5, 0.0, -1.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 26.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-2.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 23.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-2.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -2.0, -3.0, -2.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 35.0, -1.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, -1.0, -4.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 27.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0], [-6.0, -1.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -4.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 39.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, -2.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -3.0, -2.0, -3.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -3.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -2.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0], [-2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -1.0, -6.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 37.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -4.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0], [0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 28.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0], [-1.0, -3.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, -1.0, -4.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 38.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0], [0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 26.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0], [-5.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0, -5.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 28.0, -1.0, -2.0, -4.0, 0.0, -9.0, -4.0, -4.0, -2.0, -4.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 37.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0], [-7.0, -1.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, -1.0, -2.0, -1.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 42.0, -1.0, -5.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, -5.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0], [-5.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -4.0, -2.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, -2.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -2.0, -3.0, -1.0, -4.0, -1.0, -1.0, 53.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, -3.5, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, -4.0, -4.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, -1.0, -1.0, -4.0, 0.0, -1.0, -4.0], [-2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -5.0, 0.0, 8.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-6.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -4.0, -1.0, -4.0, -3.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, -3.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -9.0, -2.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 41.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, -4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -4.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -4.0, -4.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -4.0], [-5.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -4.0, -1.0, -3.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, -3.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -4.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 40.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, -4.0, -4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -4.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -4.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0], [-4.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, -3.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, -4.0, 0.0, -4.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 38.0, -3.0, -4.0, -3.0, -4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -4.0, -4.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -5.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0], [-1.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, 39.0, -3.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -4.0, -4.0, -3.0, -3.0, -9.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -4.0, -3.0, -1.0, -4.0, 0.0, -2.0, -4.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -4.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -4.0, -4.0, -3.0, 41.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -9.0, -5.0, -2.0, -3.0, -1.0, -5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -4.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0], [0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -5.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, -3.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, -4.0, 0.0, -4.0, -4.0, -3.0, 0.0, -2.0, 21.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -5.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -3.5, 0.0, -4.0, -4.0, -4.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, 20.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -5.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-2.5, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -5.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -4.0, -4.0, -4.0, -2.0, -9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 21.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-2.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.5, 0.0, -3.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, -2.0, -5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 22.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -2.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 22.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-2.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.5, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 18.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-4.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 15.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-2.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.5, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -2.0, -3.0, -5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 24.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 7.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 7.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-5.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-4.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 14.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-5.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 14.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 7.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 20.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.5, -5.0, -10.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -2.0, -4.0, 0.0, -4.0, -4.0, -5.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 22.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -4.0, -2.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -4.0, 0.0, -4.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 24.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 18.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -2.0, -4.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 21.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -4.0, 0.0, -4.0, -4.0, -4.0, 0.0, -4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 20.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-5.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -4.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 22.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-5.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, -3.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 16.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 8.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -2.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -4.0, 0.0, -4.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 22.0]]

L = pd.DataFrame(preL)

M = matrix_creator([5,6,7,9,10])
print(M)
N = matrix_creator([5,9,10])
print(N)
```

Now what I get is:

```
KeyError: '[0] not found in axis'
```

Why?

Playing with the example I discovered the function makes changes to `L` also. This is the problem then, but how to declare `martix` so as to make it work properly?

Comment: Please provide a runnable [mre]. Also `matrix` is not a native Python datatype, so tag your question according to what third-party library you're using.

Comment: Thank you for editing. Done as instructed. I understand now that I can't simply declare a python variable as a matrix, but how do I declare a copy of `L`, I still don't know.

Comment: I'm not familar with `dataframe`s, but the `[i]` in the `matrix.drop([i], axis=0, inplace=True)` is what the error message is complaining about, so check the documentation and see what the method expects the first argument passed to it to be — it sounds like it wants the value to be dropped.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

The `matrix = L` declaration was just adding another name to the object `L`. I used `matrix = L.copy()` instead and it works fine. It tried to drop an already dropped row since it wasn't a new, uncut matrix.